# What's the opposite of 'hardcoding'?

Tags: terminology

If rewriting

```
x = 2
y = 2
z = x + y
```

to

```
z = 2 + 2
```

can be described by 'hardcoding' ('hard-coding'?) values of x and y,
what's do you call its opposite, e.g.

```
z = 2 + 2
```

to

```
x = 2
y = 2
z = x + y
```

(I've never heard of 'softcoding', so I assume it's inappropriate)?

Comment: That's still hardcoding: The values `2` and `2` appear literally in your code. It would be "softcoding" if they were e.g. read from a config file or from command line arguments, etc.

Comment: When we say a computer 'reads' a config file what we really mean is it just merges code behind the scenes.

Comment: No, that's not what we mean.

Comment: Yes, it is. Unless you believe computers are actually run by fairies that 'read' your code or some other supernatural stuff.

Comment: @chachathok - the difference is whether the parameter appears literally in the source-code or not, or more precisely - whether it's determined at compile-time or at run-time (for example, when getting input from the user)

Comment: Dynamic is the adjective that comes to mind for me

Answer (score 5):

@melpomene's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729937/whats-the-opposite-of-hardcoding#comment84458960_48729937) is correct, both of your examples are hard-coding.

Anyway, in my team we call this process **parameterization**, e.g. *"we need to parameterize the threshold value used in function X"*, though I'm not sure if this is a common term.

For what it's worth, there's actually a Wikipedia entry on [Softcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding), which means what you asked for, but in a negative connotation:

> The term is generally used where softcoding becomes an anti-pattern. Abstracting too many values and features can introduce more complexity and maintenance issues than would be experienced with changing the code when required.